# Magento2: Get Category list by using admin Authentication Token?

Tags: rest-api, magento2.4, category-listing

I want to get Category list by authorization bearer key by helper function. I have created custom api module and created helper Data.php and created function for getting generated bearer key.

```
public function getApiToken()
{
$url = "http://127.0.0.1/magento241/index.php/rest";
$token_url = $url."/V1/integration/admin/token";
$username = "admin";
$password = "admin123";
 
//Authentication rest API magento2, For get access token
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$accessToken = json_decode($token);
echo $accessToken;
}
```

Then I have called getApiToken function in model file(Productlistreposito
ry.php) by below code:

```
 public function getCatList($storeId)
    {  
      $dat = $this->dataHelper->getApiToken();
      try{
          $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
          $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
          $baseUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
          $mediaUrl =$storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/category/';
          $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
          $connection = $resource->getConnection();
          $tableName = $resource->getTableName('customapi_items'); 
          $sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName." WHERE store_id = '".$storeId."'";
          $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
          if(count($result)>0){
            $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
            $categories = $categoryFactory->create();   
            $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');   
            $categories->addAttributeToFilter('level' , 2);
            $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setStore($storeId);
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
              $shopcat[] = array('id' => $category->getId(),
                  'name' => $category->getName(),
                  'image' => $mediaUrl.$category->getThumbnail(),
                  'cat_url' => $category->getUrl()
              );
              $shopoutput = array_slice($shopcat, 4);
            }
          $msg =['status_code'=> 200, 'status' => 'Success'];
          $msg1 = ['meta' =>$msg, 'data'=>$shopoutput];
          $response = $msg1;
          echo json_encode($response);die; 

          }else{
         // $data1 =['store_id'=> $storeId, 'store_name' =>$storeName,'device_id'=>$deviceid ];
          $msg =['status_code'=> 200, 'status' => 'failed', 'error'=>'Device Id Not valide'];
          $msg1 = ['meta' =>$msg, 'data'=>[]];
          $response = $msg1;
          echo  json_encode($response);die; 
         }
         }catch(\Exception $e){
          $response1 = ['status' => 'Failed', 'message' => $e->getMessage()];

         echo  json_encode($response1, $dat);die;           
         ///return $returnArray;
        }
```

In Webapi.xml, I have added:

```
 <!-- Category List Page API -->
    <route url="/V1/getCatList/:storeId" method="GET">
        <service class="Custom\Mageapi\Api\Productlistpage\ProductListingInterface" method="getCatList"/>
         <resources>
            <resource ref="self"/>
        </resources> 
    </route>
```

But still getting error, when hit api url, Where I am wrong, please suggest. Is anyone have an idea for that?

```
<response>
<message>The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.</message>
<parameters>
<resources>self</resources>
</parameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing self in the resources node, pass the resource of the section you want to access instead, pass the following;

```
<resources>
    <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::categories" />
</resources>
```

Also make sure the admin user you are using has access to the category section on the admin panel.